# Why does unity return same instance if the type is registered against two different interfaces but with only one as ContainerControlledLifeTimeManager

Tags: .net, unity-container, enterprise-library

I have two interfaces both implemented by class Apple

```
interface a { }

interface b { }

class Apple: a,b
{
}
```

Now if I register Apple against both the interfaces but only one is with ContainerControlledLifeTimeManager then resolving the other interface also returns the same instance. Why is this the way it is and anyway to work around it?

```
IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.RegisterType<a, Apple>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
container.RegisterType<b, Apple>();
var a = container.Resolve<a>();
Console.WriteLine(container.Resolve<b>().Equals(a).ToString());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Injection configuration is done against the implementation class, not the interface. This includes lifetime. So when you set the container controlled lifetime for Apple, it'll always be the same instance regardless of which interface you used to get it.

If you truly need different interfaces on the same type with different lifetimes, at this point in time the only option would be named registrations.

Comment: Just verified your answer. You're right. but your statement about injection configuration being against class, is it global and applies to all IOC containers or just Unity? any official reference?

Comment: This is how Unity works. Other containers may, and some I sure did, make other decisions. There's no ISO standards for IOC containers that I know of. :-)

Comment: I obviously meant defacto standard rather than ISO standard but thanks for your answer.